# How to make a query with Google Spreadsheets that returns items from past 15 days?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have tried using:

```
    =QUERY('Noah''s Weight'!A:D, "select * where A > date ' " &text(TODAY()-15;"yyyy-MM-dd" ) &" ' ")
```

Row 1 is the headers, column A is the time stamp from the form, and column 2 has the accompanying values I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `=QUERY(A:B, "select * WHERE datediff(now(), todate(A)) <= 15")`